# Fluid Simulation problem, some frames render others don't

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, fluid-simulation

I simulated a fruit drop into a tank (blender guru tutorial) and when preparing to render, some frames of the simulation show up on rendered view while others don't or only partly show up. Why is this?

It's not a camera cut or trimming, since in the same camera position the fluid is visible in one frame and not in the other (not completely)

It's not the visiiblity on render of the fluid sim for the same reason as above

[Link to imgur album](https://imgur.com/a/o9HJk)

Answer (score -1):

That is a bug that I have experienced many times with fluids. It does not affect final render however, so it is not that much of a problem. Just a headache.

Not really an answer I guess, but you can be content to know that you did not cause the problem. You can send in a bug report, but that is really all you can do.

Comment: thanks for the reply but in this case it does affect final render, I left it rendering and half didn't even show up.

Comment: That is strange. If you could you upload the blend file I will take a look.